# How to resolve a route name to a function?

Tags: php, laravel

Given there's a route like this:

```
Route::post('api/survey.json', ['as' => 'companies.getSurvey', 'uses' => 'CompaniesController@getSurvey']);
```

And I have the string "companies.getSurvey" how can I find what method that points to? i.e. I want back either "CompaniesController@getSurvey" or some kind of Closure that I can invoke with `app()->call(...)`.

Using Laravel 5.2

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Sorry, should have mentioned. 5.2

Comment: I've just need to update my answer as I'm not sure it will work for your version...

Comment: @RossWilson I'll check in a bit. That should hopefully be enough to get me in the right direction. Will dig through Router class if I need to :-)

Comment: I've just had a quick check and all of those methods are available in 5.2. Depending on the params that are required in your controller methods you should be ok,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Depending on your laravel version) You could do something like:

```
$route = app(\Illuminate\Routing\Router::class)->getRoutes()->getByName('companies.getSurvey');

if ($route) {
    app()->call($route->getAction()['uses']);
}
```

Comment: Should be `$route->getAction()['uses']`, but otherwise this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Route name is bound to a URL, not the method being executed. Meaning, the same route name can be used for `POST` and `GET` (and other methods), which usually lead to different controller methods (or even controllers).

**Edit**

To clarify: a single method name can point to multiple methods. Here's an example from `php artisan route:list`

> |        | GET|HEAD | test                                          | test | App\Http\Controllers\TestController@getTest                | web        |
>
> |        | POST     | test                                          | test | App\Http\Controllers\TestController@postTest               | web        |

^ Both are named `test` and point to different methods.

Comment: Yes, multiple routes can point to the same controller method, however, the OP has asked how to get the route by name and then find out which method it points to :)

Comment: What I'm saying is that same route name can point to multiple methods.

Comment: Well after some more testing - your method returns the 2nd listed controller action. Which is fine I guess for what OP wants, since it's easy to avoid naming multiple routes with the same name. I stand corrected!

Comment: Good point. I guess I'm specifically looking for the POST one, but I can just avoid the conflicts if necessary :-)